# How to correctly connect SFF8643?

Tags: sata, cable

I plan to buy Adaptec RAID controller in my workstation.
I have 8i ports with 2xSFF8643. So I need to use 2 cables SFF8643 => 4xSATA (shown on image).
But I can see on image 1 additional connector (latest on the right).

[image: cable]

What is it? How should be used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The picture isn't working at the moment, but even without it I can tell that this additional connector is a sideband connector. Basically, MiniSAS (SFF-8643) includes additional SGPIO and I2C lines, that could be connected to an enclosure and would allow controller to read enclosure status and control its indicators. If you don't have a compatible enclosure it could be just left hanging around with no collateral damage.

Comment: I will go to read about SGPIO and I2C ))